# how to read after a specific word in a file using bash shell scripting and store in arrays

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

i am new to linux and bash, here is my question :

my file (dff.v) has following lines

```
input a,b;
input [2:0] c;
output [2:0] d;
```

I have to read the file and store input variables(a,b,[2:0] c) and output variables ([2:0] d) in two different arrays,so that i can use them for further processing.
I have tried below code to store input variables but i am not getting it as expected.

```
#!/bin/bash
#assume same directory of file
counta=0;
IFS=','
for i in $(grep -w input dff.v|sed 's/[ ]//1'|sed 's/[;]//g' | sed 's/input//g');
do
 x""$counta"=$i;
 echo $i
 ((counta=counta+1))
done
```

i thought the variables will be stored as x0,x1,x2...
please help!!

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net Also It doesn't look like you have an array in your post/question.

Comment: This is also an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you *actually* trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You want to dynamically create vars? It's imposible this way `x"$counta"=$i`, but there are some tricks that may help:

```
read x"$counta" <<< "$i"
```

Or

```
printf -v x"$counta" "$i"
```

Or

```
declare x"$counta"="$i"
```

But i'd suggest use arrays instead:

```
while read name value; do
    value=${value//[\[\];]}
    case $name in
        input ) input+=("$value");;
        output) output+=("$value");;
    esac
done < dff.v

echo "input:  ${input[@]}"
echo "output: ${output[@]}"

$ ./test
input:  a,b 2:0 c
output: 2:0 d
```

Comment: I may not *like* these, but they are very useful to know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given the file diff.v and it's content.

```
baz
input a,b;
blah
input [2:0] c;
foo
output [2:0] d;
more
```

---

With a while read loop, and remove the strings that your `sed` is removing.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

i=0
while read -r input_output lines; do
  [[ $input_output == @(input|output) ]] || continue
  lines=${lines//[][;]}
  printf -v x$i '%s' "$lines"
  ((i++))
done < diff.v

printf '%s\n' "$x0" "$x1" "$x2"
```

---

The output

```
a,b
2:0 c
2:0 d
```

---

Storing the values in an associative array.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

i=0
while read -r input_output lines; do
  [[ $input_output == @(input|output) ]] || continue
  lines=${lines//[][;]}
  declare -A array["x$i"]="$lines"
  ((i++))
done < diff.v

printf '%s\n' "${array[x0]}" "${array[x1]}" "${array[x2]}"
```

Although if you just want to have a quick check what is the value of the array.

```sh
declare -p array
```

Comment: Thanks friend , can you please explain me first 3 lines of the while loop i have tried to understand but i am unable to understand what [[ $input_output == @(input|output) ]] this construct is ... is it checking for input output words or it is removing those words from lines.

Comment: The `$input_output` is just a variable that add  the first field of every line. The `@(input|output)` is an `extglob` feature which means, if either `input` or `output`, in this case skip lines that does not start with both of those words. Add `set -x` after the shebang to see which is the actual output of the script.